# How to integrate Google Analytics into a jQueryMobile website

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, google-analytics

jQueryMobile loads its first page as every site does. The usual Google Analytics integration works - the request ist tracked. But following pages are loaded asynchronously and user clicks are not tracked.

How to integrate Google Analytics into a jQueryMobile website, so that all page clicks are tracked?

Comment: [Here's an updated answer with correct event binding, using jQuery Mobile 1.3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18736218/315024)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Jon Gales has written a great article on this.

http://www.jongales.com/blog/2011/01/10/google-analytics-and-jquery-mobile/

Here's the code he recommends using:

```
$('[data-role=page]').live('pageshow', function (event, ui) {
    try {
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'YOUR_GA_ID']);

        hash = location.hash;

        if (hash) {
            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', hash.substr(1)]);
        } else {
            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
        }
    } catch(err) {

    }

});
```

**Update**

Since `live` is now deprecated you should use the `on` event instead, if you´re using jQuery 1.7+. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: You don't need the _setAccount call though. If you already have it on the first page. You can call multiple time _trackPageview after the _setAccount

Comment: jQuery Mobile 1.0 Final is packaged with jQuery Core 1.6.4 because upgrading to 1.7+ can cause problems (I've seen white-screen issues with Blackberry and 1.7). I bring this up bceuase `.on()` is a bit too new to use with jQuery Mobile 1.0 Final, however you can use `.delegate()` in the same manor.

Comment: Note that you must bind this event before jQuery Mobile executes otherwise it wont work at all (put it in your mobileinit handler). And yes, you should only call _SetAccount once but it also works like this.

Comment: doesn't work for me on android 4.0+ and ios6 with phonegap :(

Comment: You can't just replace `live` with `on`, the delegated format is different.

Answer (score 4):

For those having problems with Phonegap and google analytics :

Google code uses cookies and it doesn't work with file:// urls wich is what Phonegap uses.
The Pokki team made [a good implementation](https://developers.pokki.com/docs/tutorials.php) that uses localStorage in place of cookies.
I made a fork on github to remove the need of pokki, so here is a solution that works with phonegap as a standalone library

https://github.com/ggendre/GALocalStorage

hope this will help someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/overview.html 
http://analytics.blogspot.com/2009/10/google-analytics-now-more-powerful.html

These are references, please read for your knowladge.

Comment: -1. Neither link answers the question. The former is for GA on native iOS and Android apps; the latter has nothing to do with jQuery Mobile.