# Google Analytics & jQuery Mobile & jQuery 1.9

Tags: jquery-mobile, google-analytics

There has been a previous Question about using Google Analytics with jquery Mobile with a successful answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762950/jquery-mobile-and-google-analytics). However this was for versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.

Please can someone help alter the code so that the depreciated .live event is replaced with the current .on event. I have tried but with no success.

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    (function() {
      var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
      ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + 
          '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
}); 

$('[data-role=page]').live('pageshow', function (event, ui) {
    try {
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'YOUR_ANALYTICS_ID_GOES_HERE']);

        if ($.mobile.activePage.attr("data-url")) {
            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', $.mobile.activePage.attr("data-url")]);
        } else {
            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
        }
    } catch(err) {}

});
```

Comment: Just change live with on, final result is the same. Or you can still use old method bind, unlike live it still works.

Comment: @Gajotres `on` is not a direct replacement for `live`. The call syntax is different for delegated events.

Comment: I never said on was a direct replacement, from my experience and official documentation on is currently used for page events binding. Not to mention this is an official jQuery live method statement: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

Answer (score 3):

The code Google gives on the *Tracking Info* page you will look something like this, depending on what features you've chosen:

```
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'foo.bar']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

And you're told to put that immediately after the opening `<body>`. You should keep it in the same place with jQuery Mobile (tested on v1.3) by removing the `_trackPageview` line and adding a simple snippet to the end of that code block, giving:

```
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'foo.bar']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

    $(document).on('pageshow', ':jqmData(role="page")', function(evt, data) {
        var url = $(this).jqmData('absUrl');
        try {
            if (url) {
                url = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(url)
                _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', url.pathname + url.search + url.hash]);
            }
            else {
                _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
            }
        }
        catch(e) {}
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to .live being replaced by .on, Google is replacing ga.js with analytics.js as part of the change to Universal Analytics.

I was using a variation of the code Walf posted to track individual pages on a jQuery Mobile based site, but needed to changed it around to work with the new Universal Analytics configuration. I have the following script just after the body tag:

```
(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
    (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
    m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
})(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'site_name.com');
ga('send', 'pageview');

$(function () {
    $('[data-role=page]').on('pageshow', function (event, ui) {
        try {
            if (location.hash) {
                ga('send', 'pageview', location.hash);
            }
            else {
                ga('send', 'pageview');
            }
        }
        catch (error) {
        }
    });
});
```

Pages being listed by the location hash (e.g. #about) in Google Analytics gives me the information I want to see about how visitors are interacting with the site.

Comment: This will only work on pages that exist in the DOM already, not dynamically loaded ones, because you have not used a delegated event.

Answer (score 0):

After the opening body tag:

```
<script>
    (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
        i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
        i[r] = i[r] || function() {
            (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments);
        }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
        a = s.createElement(o),
        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
        a.async = 1;
        a.src = g;
        m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m);
    })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-XX', 'exemple.com');
</script>
```

And in each page:

```
<div data-role="page" ...>
    ...

    <script>
        $(document).off("pageshow", 'div[data-role="page"]').on("pageshow", 'div[data-role="page"]', function() {
            ga('send', 'pageview', $.mobile.path.getLocation());
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

After making the .live() to .on() change, I also had to move the script from `<head>` and to the end of `<body>`, just before the last `</div>` that was attached to the `<div data-role="page">`. Otherwise I would not get every page view.

Comment: That still won't attach properly to delegated events.